# How to get margin to be relative to text amount css

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I am creating a featured area in my Wordpress blog, to do so I have had to use z-oindex and absolute positioning; to position the text over the image. However, with absolute positioning whenever my text exceeds a certain amount the layout begins to break. Is there a way to conditionally change the top-margin based on the length of the text ? (without using javascript)

Here is my jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/7vkcLdmq/

```css
#featured_home {
    width: 960px;
    height: 325px;
}

#featured_home a {

    text-decoration: none;

    color: white;

}

.sticky {

    margin: 10px;

}

.desc {

    overflow: hidden;

    height: 265px;

}

.sticky img {

    width: 120%;

    height: auto;

    z-index: -15;

    position: relative;

}

.sticky h2 {

    z-index: 10;

    position: relative;

    display: block;

    max-width: 330px;

}

.sticky:nth-child(1) {

    width: 490px;

    height: 265px;

    overflow: hidden;

    float: left;

    margin-left: 0px;

}

.sticky:nth-child(1) h2 {

    color: white;

    font-family:'Soho Gothic Pro', arial, sans-serif;

    font-size: 22px;

    padding: 10px;

    background-color: rgba(218, 24, 114, 0.75);

    z-index: 10;

    position: absolute;

    display: inline-block;

    margin-top: 223px;

    padding-right: 183px;

    max-width: 298px;

}

.sticky:nth-child(2) {

    width: 215px;

    height: 122px;

    overflow: hidden;

    float: right;

    margin-right: 0;

}

.sticky:nth-child(2):hover {

    background-color: rgba(218, 24, 114, 0.75);

    transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;

}

.sticky:nth-child(2) h2 {

    display: none;

}

.sticky:nth-child(2):hover h2 {

    font-family:'Soho Gothic Pro', arial, sans-serif;

    font-size: 20px;

    line-height: 1.2em;

    display: inline-block;

    z-index: 10;

    position: absolute;

    max-width: 200px;

    padding: 10px;

    transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;

}

.sticky:nth-child(3) {

    width: 215px;

    height: 122px;

    overflow: hidden;

    float: right;

}

.sticky:nth-child(3):hover {

    background-color: rgba(104, 182, 109, 0.75);

    transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;

}

.sticky:nth-child(3) h2 {

    display: none;

}

.sticky:nth-child(3):hover h2 {

    font-family:'Soho Gothic Pro', arial, sans-serif;

    font-size: 20px;

    line-height: 1.2em;

    display: inline-block;

    z-index: 10;

    position: absolute;

    max-width: 200px;

    padding: 10px;

    transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;

}

.sticky:nth-child(4) {

    width: 215px;

    height: 122px;

    overflow: hidden;

    float: right;

    margin-right: 0;

}

.sticky:nth-child(4):hover {

    background-color: rgba(254, 162, 63, 0.75);

    transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;

}

.sticky:nth-child(4) h2 {

    display: none;

}

.sticky:nth-child(4):hover h2 {

    font-family:'Soho Gothic Pro', arial, sans-serif;

    font-size: 20px;

    line-height: 1.2em;

    display: inline-block;

    z-index: 10;

    position: absolute;

    max-width: 200px;

    padding: 10px;

    transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;

}

.sticky:nth-child(5) {

    width: 215px;

    height: 122px;

    overflow: hidden;

    float: right;

}

.sticky:nth-child(5):hover {

    background-color: rgba(78, 181, 224, 0.75);

    transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;

}

.sticky:nth-child(5) h2 {

    display: none;

}

.sticky:nth-child(5):hover h2 {

    font-family:'Soho Gothic Pro', arial, sans-serif;

    font-size: 20px;

    line-height: 1.2em;

    display: inline-block;

    z-index: 10;

    position: absolute;

    max-width: 200px;

    padding: 10px;

    transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;

}
```

```html
<div id="featured_home">
    <article class="sticky">
        <div class="desc">
            <div class="desc_over">
                 <h2><a href="http://stylrs.com/ctf/2015/01/08/the-best-engineering-of-2014/">The best engineering of 2014</a></h2>

            </div>
            <img width="600" height="338" src="http://stylrs.com/ctf/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/hand.jpeg" class="attachment-large wp-post-image" alt="hand">
        </div>
    </article>
    <article class="sticky">
        <div class="desc">
            <div class="desc_over">
                 <h2><a href="http://stylrs.com/ctf/2014/12/11/girls-who-code-gender-parity-by-2020/">Girls who Code – gender parity by 2020</a></h2>

            </div>
            <img width="600" height="400" src="http://stylrs.com/ctf/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/H1B8349-1280x853-1024x682-1024x682.jpg" class="attachment-large wp-post-image" alt="H1B8349-1280x853-1024x682">
        </div>
    </article>
    <article class="sticky">
        <div class="desc">
            <div class="desc_over">
                 <h2><a href="http://stylrs.com/ctf/2014/12/10/nobel-prize-winners-grid-cell-dress/">Nobel Prize winner’s ‘Grid Cell’ dress</a></h2>

            </div>
            <img width="600" height="429" src="http://stylrs.com/ctf/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/hubbble-2.jpg" class="attachment-large wp-post-image" alt="hubbble-2">
        </div>
    </article>
    <article class="sticky">
        <div class="desc">
            <div class="desc_over">
                 <h2><a href="http://stylrs.com/ctf/2014/11/21/code2040-championing-diversity-in-tech/">Code2040 – championing diversity in tech</a></h2>

            </div>
            <img width="560" height="373" src="http://stylrs.com/ctf/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/laura.jpg" class="attachment-large wp-post-image" alt="laura">
        </div>
    </article>
    <article class="sticky">
        <div class="desc">
            <div class="desc_over">
                 <h2><a href="http://stylrs.com/ctf/2014/11/13/4d-printing/">4D Printing</a></h2>

            </div>
            <img width="600" height="338" src="http://stylrs.com/ctf/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/4dprint-1024x576-1024x576.jpg" class="attachment-large wp-post-image" alt="4dprint-1024x576">
        </div>
    </article>
</div>
```

Is there another way to resolve the issue?

Comment: Perhaps you want to "anchor" the text to the bottom, instead of adjusting the top margin. Try this: https://jsfiddle.net/4h114s2q/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `bottom:0;` for `position:absolute` instead of using `margin-top` and that will work as you expect. This way the text will be extended from bottom.

Give the parent relative position:

```
.desc {
    position:relative;
}
```

Add to the sticky `h1` the following style:

```
.sticky:nth-child(1) h2 {
    position: absolute;
    botton:0;
    margin: 0;
}
```

[**JsFiddle example**](https://jsfiddle.net/7vkcLdmq/4/)

Comment: Thanks dude! that solved my problem; but just out of curiosity there is no way of doing conditional margins in CSS?

Comment: @Lukas_T Glad I could help. Unless you use JavaScript to add a dynamic value to the margin I don't think there's a CSS/HTML only solution for that. Anyhow in your case you don't need any of that. This is the best solution using `bottom:0`